# Codec error : collection columns in wso2 dss with datastax cassandra

Tags: java, collections, cassandra, codec, wso2-data-services-server

I am using datastax cassandra 5.0.4 and wso2 dss 3.5.1. I have some collections columns in my database tables(datastax). When I try to read data from those tables that have collections columns like set or list , no data return  and I have this error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not
  found for requested operation: [varchar <-> java.lang.Object]
```

table structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (test_id bigint PRIMARY KEY, test_text text, user_id bigint, expanded_urls list<text> )
```

The code is:

```
<query id="getAllTweets_param_tableName" useConfig="tweetpro">
 <expression>select test_id, test_text, user_id, expanded_urls from test</expression>
  <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
     <element column="test_id" name="test_id" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="test_text" name="test_text" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="user_id" name="user_id" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="expanded_urls" name="expanded_urls" xsdType="string"/>
  </result>
```

Comment: So is your question about what's happening?  Or what should you do about it?  Also, it's hard to answer without seeing A) your code or B) your Cassandra table definition.

Comment: The short answer, is that the DataStax Java driver does not have a codec which tells it how to convert between a `varchar` and an Object.